# Could not load UITableViewCell nib in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I'm not sure what's going on here, but prior to iOS 6, using storyboards, I would do this to create a UITableViewCell subclass.

1) UITableViewCell subclass .h and .m created for my outlets.
2) Custom UITableViewCell created on the ViewController in the storyboard.  Change its identity to the Custom UITableViewCell.  Give it the reuse identifier name.

Then when I want to instantiate the cell, in the ViewController's class, in

```
static NSString *TotalDistanceCellIdentifier = @"TotalDistanceCellIdentifier";
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TotalDistanceTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:TotalDistanceCellIdentifier];
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    TotalDistanceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TotalDistanceCellIdentifier];

    return cell;
```

In iOS 5 and 5.1, I see my UITableViewCell.  But on my iPhone running iOS 6, or the iOS 6 simulator, it crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:.....with name 'TotalDistanceTableViewCell''
```

Did something change in UItableViewCells in iOS 6?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you describe has never been correct. If it worked before, it may be that the exception is new.

You only register a nib if you've *got a separate nib file*. For prototypes within the storyboard, just dequeue with the reuse identifier and the tableView will create the new cell from your prototype.

Just remove the registerNib line and you should be fine.